# Ask user input between 2 choices for running the code

Tags: matlab

I'm creating a program to simulate a random walk and have so far produced separate code for it in both 2D and 3D. I'd like to give a user option at the beginning to do the walk in either 2D or 3D - how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the input in the command line the just use:`str = input('Ask your question','s');`
if you want a gui read about `inputdlg` in MATLAB's help

Comment: Thanks. I'm leaning more towards using the dialog function now, and using a dialog box to give the 2D and 3D options.